# Insert specific elements in specific locations of a list

Tags: r, list, insert, sapply

I have unequal sized list and I want to append specific items from one list to specific positions in another list

First list

```
dat <- structure(list(supergrp = c("D", "A", "P", "B"), 
               clusters = c("1", "2", "3", "1"), 
               items = structure(list(`1.2` = c("a", "c", "d"), 
                                      `2.1` = "b", `3` = "e", `4` = c("e", "b")),
                                 .Names = c("1.2", "2.1", "3", "4"))), 
          .Names = c("supergrp", "clusters", "items"), 
          row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

second list

```
val_to_append <- structure(list(supergrp = c("D", "A"), 
               clusters = c(1, 2), 
               items = structure(list(`1.2` = c("c", "f"), 
                                      `2.1` = c("c", "d", "e")), 
                                 .Names = c("1.2", "2.1"))), 
          .Names = c("supergrp", "clusters", "items"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to append  `val_to_append$item[[1]]` to `dat$item[[3]]`
Similarly, I want to append item `val_to_append$item[[2]]` to `dat$item[[1]]`

The required output is

```
supergrp clusters      items
1        D        1 a, c, d, e
2        A        2          b
3        P        3    e, c, f
4        B        1       e, b
```

I can do this in loop

```
dat_indx <- c(3,1)
val_indx <- c(1,2)

fin_result <- dat


for(i in seq_along(dat_indx)) {
  out_put_indx <- dat_indx[[i]]
  fin_result$items[[dat_indx[[i]]]] <- unique(c(fin_result$items[[dat_indx[[i]]]],
  val_to_append$items[[val_indx[[i]]]]))
}
```

I tried normal vector indexing such as

```
append(fin_result$items[[dat_indx]], val_to_append$items[[val_indx]])
```

without success. Is there an efficient way to do this because my list, aka, dataframe is very large hundreds of thousands of samples. 
I am thinking of `sapply` but don't have concrete idea

Comment: Is there any criteria to match ? Why `val_to_append$item[[1]]`need to append to `dat$item[[3]]` and not any other `item` ?

Comment: I have basically calculated the one to one distance between the two items and append that are most similar. But to make this task easier we can assume that `dat_indx <- c(3,1)`  and `val_indx <- c(1,2)` are available as a mapping specifying which element of the list should be appended to which element in another list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to achieve this. We append the values from `val_to_append$items` to `dat$items` using the index value which is known before hand.

```
dat_indx <- c(3,1)
val_indx <- c(1,2)

dat$items[dat_indx] <- mapply(function(x, y) 
   unique(c(dat$items[[x]], val_to_append$items[[y]])), dat_indx, val_indx)


dat
#  supergrp clusters      items
#1        D        1 a, c, d, e
#2        A        2          b
#3        P        3    e, c, f
#4        B        1       e, b
```

Although, this is another way of solving the problem I doubt how efficient it is going to be.